# ArcGIS Silverlight QueryTask Fails After Upgrade to ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-silverlight-api, query-task

Our ArcGIS Server was upgraded to 10.2.2 yesterday and the QueryTasks in my Silverlight code fail with Error Code '400': 'Unable to complete operation.'

The REST services are online and running and I've verified that the URLs are correct.

The QueryTasks worked just fine before the upgrade.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Where are you running the query task from?

Comment: It fails to work from local devenv within Visual Studio debugger and also fails when run on another one of our servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the 10.2.2 REST API doesn't support ORDER BY statements in the Query.Where property, where 10.1 did allow it.